# Can I use Minecraft on multiple PCs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I love Minecraft, and I paid 20-something dollars to get it. I want to download it onto my other PC, but I'm worried it'll make me pay all over again to get it. I think they're making you pay per account, but I'm not sure. Do you guys know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only have to pay once per account. Since you can use your account across multiple computers, you should be fine to redownload it without paying again.

Comment: just to add a point : minecraft make you paid between platform : you PC account is not valid on consoles

Comment: Thank you! I just wasn't sure. I don't have to worry about trans-platform accounts, but I do want Minecraft on more than one computer. Thank you!